# How to convert JSON string in Array. Array within Array stuck me. How to handle with it?

Tags: php, json, web-services, json-deserialization

I have a JSON String. I want it to be filled in Array. Here is Array which i receive.

My JSON Response is:

```json
{
    "model": "SyncData",
    "unique_id": "c12fb356f90d032b",
    "key": "sdjvnsdivbsnd",
    "sync_data": {
        "array_a": [{
            "a_fav": "true",
            "a_id": 1
        }, {
            "a_fav": "false",
            "a_id": 2
        }],
        "array_b": [{
            "b_fav": "false",
            "b_id": 8
        }],
        "c_array": [{
            "c_fav": "false",
            "c_id": 15996
        }],
        "patient_list_array": [{
            "unique_id": "sdvsdvsdvdsdv",
            "p_status": "false",
            "p_id": 1454943805215,
            "p_note": "2",
            "p_code": "8",
            "p_timestamp": 1454943805216,
            "p_name": "ABC XYZ",
            "p_status": 1,
            "p_room_no": "5"
        }],

        "array_d": [{
            "d_assigned_id": "30",
            "d_fav": "true"
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to store all this data in Array and from that in DataBase.

Comment: Use `json_decode($string, true)` also this is an object, which contains other properties that are arrays. I suggest you leave it as an object so dont use the second parameter i.e. `,true`

Comment: if just in array format json_decode($string, true) , if remove second param u will get the result in object form.

Comment: To be clear, your talking about transforming JSON into native PHP data types.

Comment: Ya. I ma talking about transforming JSON into native PHP. Since i am learning Web Services may be my words are not proper.

Comment: U didn't get the solution or given answers not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this json string in an array than you can use

```
json_decode($string,true);
```

Note that, second param of `json_decode` will return the array if you need result in object form than remove the second param "true".

**Your Code:**

```
$string = '{
    "model": "SyncData",
    "unique_id": "c12fb356f90d032b",
    "key": "sdjvnsdivbsnd",
    "sync_data": {
        "array_a": [{
            "a_fav": "true",
            "a_id": 1
        }, {
            "a_fav": "false",
            "a_id": 2
        }],
        "array_b": [{
            "b_fav": "false",
            "b_id": 8
        }],
        "c_array": [{
            "c_fav": "false",
            "c_id": 15996
        }],
        "patient_list_array": [{
            "unique_id": "sdvsdvsdvdsdv",
            "p_status": "false",
            "p_id": 1454943805215,
            "p_note": "2",
            "p_code": "8",
            "p_timestamp": 1454943805216,
            "p_name": "ABC XYZ",
            "p_status": 1,
            "p_room_no": "5"
        }],

        "array_d": [{
            "d_assigned_id": "30",
            "d_fav": "true"
        }]
    }
}';

$array = json_decode($string,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [model] => SyncData
    [unique_id] => c12fb356f90d032b
    [key] => sdjvnsdivbsnd
    [sync_data] => Array
        (
            [array_a] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [a_fav] => true
                            [a_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [a_fav] => false
                            [a_id] => 2
                        )

                )

            [array_b] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [b_fav] => false
                            [b_id] => 8
                        )

                )

            [c_array] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [c_fav] => false
                            [c_id] => 15996
                        )

                )

            [patient_list_array] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [unique_id] => sdvsdvsdvdsdv
                            [p_status] => 1
                            [p_id] => 1454943805215
                            [p_note] => 2
                            [p_code] => 8
                            [p_timestamp] => 1454943805216
                            [p_name] => ABC XYZ
                            [p_room_no] => 5
                        )

                )

            [array_d] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [d_assigned_id] => 30
                            [d_fav] => true
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. Got the solution. With some improvement i can use this.

Comment: @AshishVora: glad to help bro

Answer (score 1):

Simple code to use to visualise your JSON String

```
<?php
$string = '{
    "model": "SyncData",
    "unique_id": "c12fb356f90d032b",
    "key": "sdjvnsdivbsnd",
    "sync_data": {
        "array_a": [{
            "a_fav": "true",
            "a_id": 1
        }, {
            "a_fav": "false",
            "a_id": 2
        }],
        "array_b": [{
            "b_fav": "false",
            "b_id": 8
        }],
        "c_array": [{
            "c_fav": "false",
            "c_id": 15996
        }],
        "patient_list_array": [{
            "unique_id": "sdvsdvsdvdsdv",
            "p_status": "false",
            "p_id": 1454943805215,
            "p_note": "2",
            "p_code": "8",
            "p_timestamp": 1454943805216,
            "p_name": "ABC XYZ",
            "p_status": 1,
            "p_room_no": "5"
        }],

        "array_d": [{
            "d_assigned_id": "30",
            "d_fav": "true"
        }]
    }
}';
$obj = json_decode($string);
print_r($obj);
```

Which will output :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [model] => SyncData
    [unique_id] => c12fb356f90d032b
    [key] => sdjvnsdivbsnd
    [sync_data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [array_a] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [a_fav] => true
                            [a_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [a_fav] => false
                            [a_id] => 2
                        )

                )

            [array_b] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [b_fav] => false
                            [b_id] => 8
                        )

                )

            [c_array] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [c_fav] => false
                            [c_id] => 15996
                        )

                )

            [patient_list_array] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [unique_id] => sdvsdvsdvdsdv
                            [p_status] => 1
                            [p_id] => 1454943805215
                            [p_note] => 2
                            [p_code] => 8
                            [p_timestamp] => 1454943805216
                            [p_name] => ABC XYZ
                            [p_room_no] => 5
                        )

                )

            [array_d] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [d_assigned_id] => 30
                            [d_fav] => true
                        )

                )

        )

)
```